# Facebook graph explorer get bigger images from page posts

Tags: php, facebook

I have been looking for two days for a solution because I want to get bigger images from facebook page posts but I can't get it to work. It keeps sending small images. This is what I have right now and it won't work.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/$id/posts?fields=message,source,created_time,picture.width(1000).height(1000)&access_token=$accessToken
```

Comment: Try `full_picture`.

Comment: Sorry didn't work now i dont get any images

Comment: Have an example post to check out?

Comment: http://museumpakhuis.elementa.com/content/news.php

Comment: I meant the Facebook id of such a post, so that I can check the API return.

Comment: "data": [
    {
      "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/s130x130/18402874_1185530471585951_7072921097316330336_n.jpg?oh=fceb86873e45de5a8385f2ea94d445cb&oe=5981CC22",
      "id": "362640870541586_1185530471585951"
    },

Comment: So what is the problem with using `full_picture` then? It returns https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/18402874_1185530471585951_7072921097316330336_n.jpg?oh=5156a4b0a4582d5fb396e4605b0c585b&oe=59C0C349, which is the largest version of that image available.

Comment: i think thats a problem in my code then because it doesn't return the pictures i thing i know why so thank you so much

Comment: it fixed it thank you